# To what extent does the cooking time impact the nutritional content when boiling potatoes?

Tags: food, nutrition, heat

I wonder to what extent the cooking time impacts the nutritional content when boiling unpeeled potatoes with unsalted water.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/340060-does-boiling-potatoes-reduce-their-vitamins/ says:

> Boiling potatoes whole in their skins minimizes the amount of vitamin C that is lost. According to the Food
>   and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations, boiling unpeeled potatoes results in losses of up to 30
>   percent of vitamin C, but boiling peeled potatoes can cause losses of up to 40 percent. About 2 percent of the
>   vitamin B-6 is lost due to boiling potatoes, as well as about 23 percent of the thiamine. A 3.5-ounce serving of
>   potato boiled in the skin provides 22 percent of the daily value for vitamin C, but boiled peeled potatoes
>   provide only 12 percent. Peeling potatoes before boiling can also increase vitamin B-6 losses, with unpeeled
>   boiled potatoes containing 15 percent of the DV per 3.5-ounce serving and peeled boiled potatoes containing
>   only 13 percent of the DV. There is no difference in thiamine content between peeled and unpeeled boiled
>   potatoes.
>
> [...]
>
> The higher the temperature and the longer the cooking time, the more of the vitamins will be lost

However, it does not mention how the loss curve looks like.

Comment: I don't understand your exact question. The quoted text clearly says that *The higher the temperature and the longer the cooking time, the more of the vitamins will be lost*. In general, the extent of leaching will depend exponentially with time (the process follows a first order kinetics).

Comment: @WYSIWYG exponential could be an answer. I am wondering what the loss curve looks like.